# Passing data from function to template in a Django view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have an ordinary view, which renders a template with some variables.
In this example, two values called `x, y` are retrieved from a form. I would like to render on my template the addition of those two numbers, so i tried this:

```
def myview():

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            x = request.POST['x']
            y = request.POST['y']
            MyFunction(x, y)
            send = form.save()
            send.save()
            messages.success(request, f"Success")
    //Some other operations here..

    return render(request, "main/mytemplate.html", 
                  context={"mydata": mydata})


def MyFunction(x, y):

    mydata = x*y

    return mydata
```

This problem gives an error, of course, because `MyData` is a variable defined inside a function, so `myview` can't see it. Is there a way to pass the variable to the view? I know that i could do the same operation all inside the view, without defining a function, but i would rather use a function since it makes the code easier to read.

Comment: You're ignoring the return of `MyResult` function call. In `MyFunction(x, y)` replace with `mydata = MyFunction(x, y)`. Also, use snake casing for function names (`my_function` instead of `MyFunction`) [PEP8 Function and Variable Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names).

Comment: You say addition and you are doint `x*y` instead of `x+y` and you view is wrong it is not taking `request` parameter